# Activity inside a non-activity fragment class freezing the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am working on localizing my Android application using Kotlin and want to set the content to spanish everytime the radio button is pressed. For that, whenever the button is clicked I fire up a `LanguageActivity` which basically is supposed to set the locale value to espanol. However, I notice that when the `LanguageActivity` loads, the screen turns white and nothing happens unless I hit the back button. I don't see any error message too, so I'm not sure what's happening. I am loading the activity from within a non-activity `NewsFragment` class. I'm using Android API 30.

Also, I'm pretty much new to all to this and would greatly appreciate if you could provide feedback on the localization logic in `LanguageActivity` and `ContextUtils`and suggest any better approach.

**NewsFragment**

```
internal fun showLanguagePopup(anchorView: View, gravity: Int) {
        val popupBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemNewsLanguagePopupBinding>(layoutInflater, R.layout.item_news_language_popup, null, false)

        viewModel.availableLanguages
            .forEachIndexed { index, language ->
                val button = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_news_language_popup_button, popupBinding.gLanguages, false) as RadioButton
                button.text = language.toNameString(activity!!)
                button.id = index
                button.isChecked = viewModel.getCurrentLanguage() == language
                popupBinding.gLanguages.addView(button)
            }

        val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupBinding.root, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            popupWindow.elevation = 10f
        }

        popupBinding.bCancel.setOnClickListener { popupWindow.dismiss() }
        popupBinding.bOk.setOnClickListener {
            val selectedLanguageOrdinal = popupBinding.gLanguages.checkedRadioButtonId
            if (selectedLanguageOrdinal >= 0) {
                viewModel.setupLanguage(viewModel.availableLanguages[selectedLanguageOrdinal])
                val intent = Intent(activity, LanguageActivity::class.java)
                //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
                drawerLogicView.onBackPressed()
            }
            popupWindow.dismiss()
        }

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView, 0, -anchorView.height / 2, gravity)
    }
```

**LanguageActivity**

```
package com.oigetit.oigetit.ui.news.list

import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.oigetit.oigetit.utility.ContextUtils

import java.util.*


class LanguageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        val localeToSwitchTo = Locale("es")
        val localeUpdatedContext: ContextWrapper? = ContextUtils.updateLocale(newBase, localeToSwitchTo)
        super.attachBaseContext(localeUpdatedContext)
    }
}
```

**ContextUtils**

```
package com.oigetit.oigetit.utility

import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.os.Build
import android.os.LocaleList
import java.util.*


class ContextUtils(base: Context?) : ContextWrapper(base) {

    companion object {
        fun updateLocale(context: Context, localeToSwitchTo: Locale?): ContextWrapper? {
            var context = context
            val resources: Resources = context.resources
            val configuration: Configuration = resources.getConfiguration() // 1
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                val localeList = LocaleList(localeToSwitchTo) // 2
                LocaleList.setDefault(localeList) // 3
                configuration.setLocales(localeList) // 4
            } else {
                configuration.setLocale(localeToSwitchTo) // 5
            }
            //val resources: Resources = context.resources
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration) // 6
            } else
            {
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
            }
            return ContextUtils(context) // 8
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't start your activity with that intent.

add `startActivity(intent)` below the `val intent = Intent(activity, LanguageActivity::class.java)` line.

> I am loading the activity from within a non-activity NewsFragment class and don't want to use the MainActivity for loading

For this part of your question, fragments are completely depend on activities, therefore they can't start another activity inside themselves.